# Formato data javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Estava olhando a [ISO8601](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) que fala sobre o formato da `string` passada como argumento para o [objeto date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).
Nesse site, a data retornada é de ontem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou passando o valor '2017-08-03' para o objeto date e ele me retorna a data de ontem, veja:

```js
data = '2017-08-03'
console.log(new Date(data));
```

Porque no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/158bo3u4/1/) ocorre resultado diferente?

```
Wed Aug 02 2017 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A confusão acontece somente quando se usa `alert`, se trocarmos por `console.log` tudo está certo. A diferença é que o `alert` chama `toString` para printar o conteúdo de algum objeto, mais ou menos assim:

```
data = '2017-08-03'
console.log(new Date(data).toString());
```

O resultado será:

> Wed Aug 02 2017 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Errado também. Mas se invocarmos `toISOString`:

> 2017-08-03T00:00:00.000Z

O importante é que o objeto *date* está sendo criado corretamente com base na [string](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) passada.

Comment: Algum fã saiu distribuindo down votes anônimos